# Determine the sample's variance

Tags: statistics

Ok so I have a problem which I'm not sure how to resolve, it is probably something simple but I can't seem to get it, anyway here's what the problem says.

There is a population with an unknown variance $\sigma^2$. A confidence interval for $\mu$ with a 95% confidence and a sample size of 16 is $]42.7,49.3[$. Determine the variance for this sample.

This is where things don't add up. Basically $s^2$ = 38.3529, according to the answer. I'm doing this:

$\frac{(10 - 1)s^2}{\chi^2_{0.025,15}} = 49.3$

Where  $\chi^2_{0.025,15} = 6.26214 $

Nonetheless, it does not give me the answer and if I try it with the other side of the interval it gives me an even stranger number. Can someone help me, or give me a hint as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Depending on the sample size one works with the $t$-distribution or $\chi^2-$ distribution. As a rule, if $n < 30$ then one uses the $t$-distribution. The confidence interval for the mean $\overline{X}$ is then $\overline{X}  \pm t_{\alpha/2} s/\sqrt{n}$. This is under the assumption of normality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really a lot simpler than that.  Assuming that the sample was drawn from a normal distribution with unknown mean and variance, the Wald $100(1-\alpha)\%$ CI is of the form $$\bar x \pm \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}} t_{n-1,\alpha/2},$$ where $t_{n-1,\alpha/2}$ is the critical value for a Student's $t$ distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom at a two-sided significance level of $\alpha$; i.e., it is the upper $\alpha/2$ quantile satisfying $$\Pr[T > t_{n-1,\alpha/2}] = \alpha/2.$$

Since $\alpha = 0.05$ for a $95\%$ confidence level, and $n = 16$, we have $$t_{15,0.025} = 2.13145.$$  Then the midpoint of the CI is $$\bar x = \frac{42.7 + 49.3}{2} = 46,$$ hence $$s = \frac{(49.3 - 46)\sqrt{16}}{2.13145} \approx 6.19297.$$  This is the sample standard deviation, so the sample variance is $s^2 = 38.3529$, as claimed.

Comment: Yes, I see, much simpler than I thought. Thanks for the help.